# Xcode 5 compiling against ios6.1 does not preserve layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7

Im having layout issues with projects that target iOS6.1 SDK that are built in xCode 5. My view controllers seem to extend under the top nav bar and the top nav bar is transparent. Setting 'extend edges' has no effect since I am compiling against iOS6.1.

Has anyone been able to find a way to use XCode 5 for pre iOS7 apps or do I basically have to use XCode 4?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was having the same problem with my iOS6.x app when built with Xcode 5. It looks like in Xcode 5, being careless with your UINavigationBar translucency has serious, but easily fixable consequences.

In my case, making the fix in Interface Builder (IB) made sense as the quickest & easiest way to go. Take a look at this screen grab that shows the translucency check boxes that I unchecked to fix the problem in my app with a UITabBarController and four tabs (i.e. five things had to be un-checked in IB):

[image: Using IB to fix VCs of iOS 6 app built with Xcode 5 from flowing under navBar]

Answer (score 0):

try to do that

first press on view

[image]

then

[image]

Comment: Thanks ill give it a try however, im not using auto layout.